# NUnit GUI runner command line args

Tags: nunit

In looking at the available command line arguments for the nunit.exe, I haven't been able to find a way to specify the path and filename of the TestResults.xml file (it always ends up in the same folder as the test fixture).  I know this can be specified when using nunit-console.exe via the /xml argument, but is there there any way to specify this for nunit.exe?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the console application if it supports the functionality you are looking for? What's your reason for using the GUI application?

Comment: Good question.  I'm using the GUI runner to debug my code (I have my Visual Studio environment set up to launch it when I hit F5).  It's more convenient to be able to pick and choose the tests to run via the GUI.  Ultimately, the location of the TestResults.xml file isn't a huge deal for me.  I was just curious if there's a switch or a configuration that I'm missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I'm trying to do isn't possible.  No biggie.